# Check if session exists when I back to main page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a project on **"somepage.com"** and when I join to my page, always I see again the login form, I want to check when I go back to **"somepage.com"** if previously I logged on the page I want to go to `/admin` or `/sales` and If I not logged go to `/`

Laravel 5.8

Comment: Your login page should be protected by `auth` middleware to prevent this. [Here's the docs on that](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#protecting-routes)

Comment: i think you need to read laravel documentation.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check manually, you can use Auth::check() this will return if the session is active.

In your controller before rendering the view code will look somewhat like this:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    // return redirect as you wish.
}

// return redirect to login page.
```

don't forget to `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`